# Mi página web se demora en cargar por primera vez desde el sitio de producción

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, aplicación-web, web

Tengo un sistema web que he creado en `C#` con `MVC` y base de datos `MySQL`. Cuando lo pruebo desde mi computador(localhost) no tengo ningún problema, pero cuando lo pruebo desde un sitio web de producción donde está alojado, siempre demora por primera vez, lo que hay que hacer es presionar la tecla `F5`, y ahí carga bien la página, después, si quiero volver a abrir la página, carga bien.

El problema siempre se da cuando cuando se carga por primera vez la página.
Sé que el problema no es con la base de datos, ya que cuando se carga el inicio de la página, no hace ninguna llamada a la BD.

He deducido a pensar que el problema puede ser la librería de `jQuery` que tengo en el proyecto o la de `Bootstrap`, pero lo encuentro difícil, ya que desde mi computador funciona bien, lo otro que he llegado a pensar que puede ser el cache o algo para habilitar los cookies desde el servidor de producción.

La verdad, hay bastante difícil de detectar la causa del problema de demora. Si alguien sabe algo, se lo agradecería en gran manera.

Solo para descartar causas, he estado pensado, que una de las causas de mi problema, ¿podría ser la clase InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute que tengo definida en mi proyecto(ya en MVC, se genera esta clase) que está en la carpeta filter? lo modifique, comentando código que creo que no me sirven, de manera que lo deje de esta forma:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        //public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        //{
        //    Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);


        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Se me ocurren 2 cosas:
1: Desde las maquinas cliente haz un Ping por nombre al servidor para ver si resuelve bien la ip o se demora 'N'. Si tienes bien configurado el dns, Tu servicio, debería responder rápido, igual que lo hace cuando estas en local. 2: Como resuelves la identidad del usuario? por Autenticación de formulario basado en BBDD ? por windows integrated ntlm kerberos ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Este comportamiento se puede dar por diferentes causas. Voy a enumerar una lista de cosas que yo revisé (ya que al igual a mi me había pasado lo mismo) para poder determinar el problema.

1. En tu archivo `web.config` revisa que no se tenga habilitado el modo `debug` `<compilation debug="false">`
2. La publicación del sitio debe ser en modo `Release`
3. Dale clic derecho a tu proyecto Web y luego `Propiedades`, en la sección `Package/Publish Web` activa el `CheckBox` que dice **`Exclude generated debug symbols`**, con esto no se generan los archivos `.pdb` que contienen los símbolos del modo `debug`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. El modo de inicio de tu `Pool` deberá estar activado como **`Always     Running`**. Esto lo puedes configurar en el `IIS Manager` >>  `Grupo de  aplicaciones` >> Clic derecho a tu `Pool` y luego en `Configuración Avanzada` >> `Modo de inicio` >> `Siempre corriendo` (`AlwaysRunning`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que en tu caso, esta información sea funcional.

Comment: Ok, se bastante lógico y buena tu respuesta, lo probaré y luego te cuento como me fue

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez debas hacer algún tipo de configuración en tu IIS para habilitar el "Application Initialization Module",

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization

Comment: Hola @Mauricio Atanache, existiria la posibilidad de que la clase InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute, que se encuentra en la carpeta Filters(esto se crea cuando es proyecto en MVC), tenga que ver en el problema, porque comente y quite ciertas lineas de código, que según yo creía que eran innecesarias, edite mi pregunta para copiar el código de esta clase, y ver como lo tengo definido.